# How many fixed points of $\tan x$ are there if $x>0$, $x\neq k \pi + \frac{\pi}{2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, fixed-points

Is the following statement is true  or false

> Consider  the  function  $\tan x  $ on the  set $S=\{ x \in \mathbb{R}  : x \ge 0  , x \neq k \pi + \frac{\pi}{2}   \text{ for  any } k \in \mathbb{N}  \cup \{0\}  \}$ We  say  that it has  a  fixed point in $S$  if  there  exist $x \in S$  such that  $\tan x = x$.
> Then there  are infinitely  many fixed  points

**My attempt** : I think this statement is false because the only point that satisfied $\tan x =x$ is $0$ .

$\implies  \tan 0 =0 $

Therfore  there is  a unique fixed point.

Comment: How does your attempt say anything about other points (you just claim it is so)?  You could graph the functions $y=x$ and $y=\tan(x)$, at least, before making any claim.

Comment: okay @Manifoldski  You mean fixed points are the intersection of $y$ and $x$. Am i right ?

Comment: Yes.  More formally, for any function $~f(x),~$ a fixed point is an element $~x~$ in the domain of the function $~f(x),~$ such that $~f(x) = x.$  In the  present example, you have that $~f(x) = \tan(x),~$ with the domain of $~f(x)~$ being a subset of the real numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider function $f(x)=\tan x - x$.
Let $k\in\Bbb N_{>0}$.

- $f(k\pi)=-x< 0$
- $\lim_{x\to {k\pi+\frac\pi2}^-}=\infty>0$ since $\lim_{x\to {k\pi+\frac\pi2}^-}\tan x=\infty$

By the intermedia value theorem, since both $\tan(x)$ and $x$ are continuous on the interval $[k\pi, k\pi+\frac\pi2)$, there is value $x_k\in (k\pi, k\pi+\frac\pi2)$ such that $f(x_k)=0$.

$x_1, x_2, \cdots$ are all distinct since $x_1<2\pi<x_2<3\pi<x_3\cdots$.
Hence there are infinitely many fixed points in $S$, $x_1, x_2, \cdots.$

Comment: In fact, we can show there are exactly $n$ fixed points in $S$ in  $[0, n\pi]$.