# A question on $F(x)= x\cdot \sin(1/x)$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Given that
> $F:[0,1]\to\Bbb R$ is defined by $$F(x)=\begin{cases}x\sin (1/x),&\text{ if } 0<x\le 1\\0,&\text{ if }x=0\end{cases},$$
> does there exist a countable collection ofclosed intervals $
> {I_k}$ such that $F$ is either increasing or decreasing on each $I_k$?
> and that $\bigcup_{k\in\Bbb  N}I_k=[0,1]$?

I'm stuck on its derivative $F'(x)=\sin\left(\dfrac1x\right)-\dfrac1x\cos\left(\dfrac1x\right)$ on which he rewrites as $\varphi(t)=\sin t-t\cos t $, where now $t\in (0,\infty).$.

In the [following link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.6871.pdf)
was, the justfication that there, infact, exist closed intervals satisfying such condition, but I can't really figure out the closed form for $I_k.$

> Is there any close form for $I_k$?

Any insights/help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Since $F'$ has the intermediate value property, on $(0,1]$ the points where $F$ changes monotonicity is at most the number of points where $F'$ equals $0$. So you need to argue that $F'$ has only countably many roots, which is made easier by the rewrite from $x$ to $t$. The closed forms, though, will be slightly harder to argue. You need to get the roots of $F'$ explicitly and then find which of them is an actual maxima/minima.

Comment: [Somewhat related(?)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4656994)

Comment: Be cautious with this question. There is a trap in it for the unwary.

Comment: As for "closed forms", why do you need them? You are not asked to produce the exact intervals, just to determine if they exist, that there countably many, and if their union is $[0,1]$. None of those - not even the last - requires you to have some exact expression for the end points.

Comment: @PaulSinclair thank you so much for the response, its existence is what I need, which I already found on the link stated. I was just curious for the interval form of $I_k$.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Thank you so much for this valuable insight.